# reference error in javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I need to store the value of php variable $Q_ID in javascript array at index 0. Here is my code for storing it in javascript array record[0].

```
var record= [];
var choice= [];
var correct=[];

 record[0]=<?php echo $Q_ID ?>;/* Showing refernce error (ReferenceError: CSE6014 is not defined record[0]=CSE6014) */;

 correct[0]=<?php echo $corr ?>;
```

And this is the php code to get the value of Q_ID. I have placed the php code before  tag in the page and the javascript code is in the body at the last position.

```
$sql= mysql_query( "select * from questions where Q_ID like '{$code}%' order by RAND() limit 1" ) or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$Q_ID = $rows['Q_ID'];
$question= $rows['Question'];
$opt1=$rows['Option_1'];
$opt2=$rows['Option_2'];
```

I have placed the php code before  tag in the page and the javascript code is in the body at the last position. But everytime I execute this code it shows reference error in firebug console window.

ReferenceError: CSE6014 is not defined
record[0]=CSE6014;/* Showing refernce error (ReferenceError: CSE6014 is not defi...

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `record[0] = '<?php echo $Q_ID ?>';`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use statement like this        if(record.length< <?php echo $NoOfQuestion-1; ?>)       where $NoOfQuestion is an integer.

Comment: What's the value of `echo $NoOfQuestion;`

Comment: I am retrieving its value from database. Consider it can be any integer value (maximum 100).

Comment: You can simply make a use of another variable as `var myvar = <?php echo $NoOfQuestion; ?>-1` and `if(record.length< myvar; ?>)` and be sure that the value within your php code must be int and not a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `$Q_ID` and `$corr` are `strings`, you need to surround `string` with `quotes`. You can use either single quote `'` or double quote `"`.

Use following code(Notice the quotes around the PHP tags):

```
record[0] = '<?php echo $Q_ID ?>';
correct[0] = '<?php echo $corr ?>';
```

Comment: Sorry sir but its not working in this case. "$NoOfQuestion" is a number not string.

Comment: @vishnupriya Try `if(record.length< parseInt('<?php echo $NoOfQuestion-1; ?>')`

Comment: It is giving this error in firebug console                                                         SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
if(record.length< parseInt('<br />

Comment: @vishnupriya `if(record.length< parseInt('<?php echo $NoOfQuestion-1; ?>'))`

Comment: Sir it is giving unterminated string literal syntax error

Comment: @vishnupriya Please create `jsfiddle` of the issue, it'll be easier to solve